# Initialize static variable with the argument of a function

Tags: c, function, static, initialization

How can I do something like this?

```
void function(int n)
{
    static int number = n;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Static variables are initialized at compile time.

Comment: Besides, at which invocation of the function should the assignment with n occur?

Comment: Do you want `number = n` on only the very first call of `function()` , or on every call (in which case you don't need it to be static) ?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I wont say during compile time, rather, just before starting the execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to initialize the static variable to `n` during the first invocation of the function, you can do it like this:

```
void function(int n)
{
    static int initialized = 0;
    static int number;

    if (!initialized) {
        number = n;
        initialized = 1;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

You can't initialize `number` to `n` directly since `number` is initialized at compile time, while `n` is known only at run time.

Comment: It's initialized at first time `function` is being called: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables re initialized the first time control passes through their declaration (unless their initialization is zero- or constant-initialization, which can be performed before the block is first entered). On all further calls, the declaration is skipped. the OP's code looks legit to me although it doesn't really useful in practice;

Comment: That's C++, this question is about C.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

Quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §6.7.9/P4

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has `static` or thread storage duration
>   shall be constant expressions or string literals.

To elaborate, the objects with `static` storage duration are initialized only once, prior to the execution to the program. Thereby, it is not possible to use a run-time value to be used as the explicit initializer.

Related, from chapter §6.2.4

> An object whose identifier is declared [...] with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

Comment: @Luke seems like a problem in your design, if you have to initalize it in every call, why'd you need `static`?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to discuss a workaround. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm calling this function in a while loop with always the same argument. So I want to initialize it only once, and whenever the function is called I want to work with the modified static value.

Comment: @luke `static int number  = 0; if (number == 0) { number = n;};` could be enough. However you should rather return the modified `number` and pass it back in as an argument on the next invocation , so you avoid a whole class of potential issues.